# Unmarshalling Optional Parameter in Jax-WS

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

When in soap UI I use the following request, everything works fine:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:_0="http://types.kamal.com/5_0/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <_0:getNumberOfMatches>
         <Id>XXX</Id>
         <erPassword>XXX</erPassword>
         <name>KOL</name>
     <timing>
         <start>XXXX</start>
     </timing>      
      </_0:getNumberOfMatches>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If I pass an element at the root level `<abc>1</abc>`, it still works fine. The request becomes like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:_0="http://types.kamal.com/5_0/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <_0:getNumberOfMatches>
         <Id>XXX</Id>
         <erPassword>XXX</erPassword>
         <name>KOL</name>
     <timing>
         <start>XXXX</start>
     </timing>
     <abc>1</abc>   
      </_0:getNumberOfMatches>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**However if I add this tag `<abc>1</abc>` under timing element, it starts giving me Un-Marshaling exception.**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:_0="http://types.kamal.com/5_0/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <_0:getNumberOfMatches>
         <Id>XXX</Id>
         <erPassword>XXX</erPassword>
         <name>KOL</name>
     <timing>
         <start>XXXX</start>
         <abc>1</abc>
     </timing>      
      </_0:getNumberOfMatches>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**If Anybody has any idea regarding the Unmarshalling mechanism used by JAX-WS.
And why it works at the parent level and it stops working in case of nested tag.**

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: `<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"abc"). Expected elements are &lt;{}start></faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm from your wsdl, whether you have a special 'tag' at the parent level?

```
<xs:any namespace="##other" />
```

The existence of this `xmlAnyElement` could be the cause of the parent `<getNumberOfMatches>`accepting new elements.

On the other hand, when you put the new `<abc>` tag in the `<timing>` tag, it does not work. Because the `<timing>` tag would not be having the `xmlAnyElement` in the wsdl defined.

You could find the detailed working here : http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp

Let me know if this solved your issue.